# Getting 2 random letters sequentially from a string

Tags: php

So getting 2 random letters from a string is easy enough to find an answer to:

```
$var1 = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($var1, 2)), 0, 2);
```

But what if you want to get 2 letters sequentially from a string,Is there a way to do it without using a loop?

For instance, if you have a string named "Colorado", and if the first random character grabbed was "r", it would only get a letter from the remaining 3 letters for the 2nd chosen letter.

Comment: you mean you want `ado` returned? *it would only get a letter from the remaining 3 for the 2nd.* 

Comment: getting 2 letters.. so if the first letter it got was "r", it would then grab either a, d, or o for the second letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely other ways, here is one.

Pick random char, use [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), shuffle it then grab first 2 chars.

```
<?php
$var = 'Colorado';

// pick random
$picked = $var[rand(0, strlen($var))];

// grab string after first occurrence
$parts = stristr($var, $picked);

// shuffle it
$part = str_shuffle($parts);

echo $part[0].$part[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/uDvRX

*your need to add some undefined checks to handle no matches etc

Comment: i used `$parts` as originally used explode, feel free to refactor it ;p